# React - How can I reverse the order of dynamic children lists that have a key unique id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this JS fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/justindeal/8hqqgbuf/5/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=8hqqgbuf

There is a list that is created from an array.  I want to have the newest entries on top instead of coming in at the bottom.  I can't find anything on how to fine tooth control this other than adding the xxxxx.id for the key which is already accomplished.

here is the code sample.

```
var NotesList = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var notes = this.props.notepad.notes;

    return (
        <div className="note-list">
            {
                notes.map(function (note) {
                    return (
                        <NoteSummary key={note.id} note={note}/>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Worth noting - if your component is stateless, maybe you should consider using `Stateless Function`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions

Answer (score 2):

So I figured with a common javascript method you could reverse the order of the array via the map method and it worked.

```
var NotesList = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var notes = this.props.notepad.notes;

    return (
        <div className="note-list">
            {
                notes.reverse().map(function (note) {
                    return (
                        <NoteSummary key={note.id} note={note}/>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: `reverse` works in-place, so your original `notes` array gets modified.
Beware that this won't work if you need to modify `notes`.

To avoid any confusion, you could instead reverse a copy and assign it to notes:
`var notes = [...this.props.notepad.notes].reverse()`